# Taxonomy field in code

Tags: taxonomy-terms, installation

I am working on a module that has an install file that creates a taxonomy with postal codes.
And then imports all contacts from a csv file.

Now i would like to add a field to my taxonomy (boolean).

How would i approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to create Vocabulary before adding terms to it

Comment: Dear Pravin, Thanks for your reply.
I am working with this post https://www.drupal.org/node/774884 
Now trying to figure out how to set the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a vocabulary  with fields

```
taxonomy_vocabulary_save((object) array(
      'name' => 'Vocabulary Name',
      'machine_name' => 'vocabulary_machine_name',
    ));

// Create a field
 $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_your_field',
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'your label'
  );
  field_create_field($field);

  // Attach the field to our taxonomy entity
  $instance = array(
      'field_name' => 'field_your_field',
      'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
      'bundle' => 'vocabulary_machine_name',
      'label' => 'Label',
      'description' => 'Description',
      'required' => true,
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'text_textfield',

      )
  );
  field_create_instance($instance);
```

You can create terms like below :

```
 $term = new stdClass();
    $term->name = ‘Your Term name’;
    $term->vid = 'vocabulary id'; 
    $term->field_your_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = ‘data’; 
    taxonomy_term_save($term);
```